# how to create change using gerrit in browser

Tags: git, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am using gerrit rest api create change in browser

1. 'POST /changes/'
   [change info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEqyc.png)
2. 'PUT /changes/{change-id}/edit/path%2fto%2ffile'
3. 'PUT /changes/{change-id}/edit:message'
4. 'POST /changes/{change-id}/edit:publish'[Conflict 409](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJcX6.png)

   on step 4,gerrit response [409 Conflict] ,how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /changes/ endpoint is used to create the change, this is the first step of the [Code Review workflow](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#code-review) to have something integrated in Gerrit using REST.

After that you need (at least):

- Use the [Change Edit](https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#edit-endpoints) endpoints to edit the change.
- Use the [Set Review](https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-review) endpoint to review the change.
- Use the [Submit Change](https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#submit-change) endpoint to submit (integrate) the change.

If you have conflict you'll get an error in the last step (submit). This means that you have based your work in a commit which is not the latest one in the branch and you need to rebase your commit and create another change patchset.

To learn more about the rebase process see the following:

- [Cannot merge in Gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583710/cannot-merge-in-gerrit/37590769#37590769)
- [How to submit my changes in abc file which is old version while git has same abc file with new changes by other developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042254/how-to-submit-my-changes-in-abc-file-which-is-old-version-while-git-has-same-abc/50042640#50042640)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I use rest api create change
1,'POST /changes/'
2,'PUT /changes/{change-id}/edit/path%2fto%2ffile'
3,'PUT /changes/{change-id}/edit:message'
4,'POST /changes/{change-id}/edit:publish'
on step 4,response [409 Conflict] ,how to fix?

Comment: I added more info to the answer.